# iPad AdMob integration issues - ads showing but not much more

Tags: ipad, admob

I have an AdMob ad integrated in my iPad game app and seeing two issues:

1. The test ad I get is the wrong size. 
   I am not sure if this is intentional or will fix itself when the app is live.
2. When I click the test ad in my app (AdMob Test iPhone Ad), it disappears and I get no more ads.
   Neither 'applicationWillTerminateFromAd' or 'didPresentFullScreenModalFromAd' are called.
   The app continues to run as expected, but no more ads show.

Is that normal? 
What can it be if not normal?

Thanks in advance to any of you masters that can shed light on this issue - otherwise, my app is ready to be submitted!

ps. I have free codes for the paid version if anyone interested!!

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it, and here is how:
1. I used the wrong size. I tried to get a 748x90 pixel ad. The correct size is 748x110
This resolved the wrong size issue.

2. The test ad messes up for some reason, but using the following function let me test with real ads and they worked.


Happy developer - next stop: Apple!

```
- (BOOL)useTestAd {
    return NO;
}
```